# How to combine simplecov coverage/index.html files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, circleci, simplecov

I am using `simplecov` for rspec coverage. When I run `RAILS_ENV=test rspec` on my local, it generates a single `coverage/index.html` file but on CircleCI we are using 2 containers for rspec coverage. 2 separate containers generates two separate `coverage/index.html` files. i.e. one against each container.
I want a single `coverage/index.html` on Circle CI. Is there a way to combine or merge both index files? or generates a single file against multiple containers?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this excellent writeup](https://rubyyagi.com/merge-simplecov-circleci/), you want to merge `.resultset.json` files.

There will be implementation details of where the files are stored and what they're named, but in the end you should end up with a separate CI run step that merges the resultsets and generates the final HTML report by calling `SimpleCov.collate`.

See also [SimpleCov's readme on merging results](https://github.com/simplecov-ruby/simplecov#merging-test-runs-under-different-execution-environments).